# Does OrientDB work in Internet Explorer or MS Edge?

Tags: orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 2.2.26 and I wanted to know if OrientDB Studio officially works with IE or Edge browsers. For me it is only currently working in Chrome.

Thanks,

Bikrum

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB Studio works with Chrome, Firefox, Opera but it doesn't with Internet Explorer me too.

Hope it helps

Regards